# Is there any way to add more difficulty level in my Sudoku code written in python with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner in python GUI using tkinter. I'm searching for Sudoku puzzle code so I found one (code given below) its working fine but I'm not able to add more difficulty level such as very easy, easy, medium, hard, very hard in it. Please help me!

```
import random
import time
import os
import tkinter.tix
import pickle
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import *
from tkinter.tix import FileSelectBox, Tk

random.seed(time.time())


# There are probably a few bugs in this class, and it could be implemented 
# better I think.
class SudokuBoard:
    """
    Data structure representing the board of a Sudoku game.
    """


    def __init__(self):
        self.clear()

    def clear(self):
        """
        Empty the board.
        """
        self.grid = [[0 for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
        self.locked = []

    def get_row(self, row):
        return self.grid[row]

    def get_cols(self, col):
        return [y[col] for y in self.grid]

    def get_nearest_region(self, col, row):
        """
        Regions are 3x3 sections of the grid.
        """
        def make_index(v):
            if v <= 2:
                return 0
            elif v <= 5:
                return 3
            else:
                return 6
        return [y[make_index(col):make_index(col)+3] for y in 
                self.grid[make_index(row):make_index(row)+3]]

    def set(self, col, row, v, lock=False):
        if v == self.grid[row][col] or (col, row) in self.locked:
            return
        for v2 in self.get_row(row):
            if v == v2:
                raise ValueError()
        for v2 in self.get_cols(col):
            if v == v2:
                raise ValueError()
        for y in self.get_nearest_region(col, row):
            for x in y:
                if v == x:
                    raise ValueError()
        self.grid[row][col] = v
        if lock:
            self.locked.append((col, row))

    def get(self, col, row):
        return self.grid[row][col]

    def __str__(self):
        strings = []
        newline_counter = 0
        for y in self.grid:
                strings.append("%d%d%d %d%d%d %d%d%d" % tuple(y))
                newline_counter += 1
                if newline_counter == 3:
                    strings.append('')
                    newline_counter = 0
        return '\n'.join(strings)

def sudogen_1(board):
    """
    Algorithm:
        Add a random number between 1-9 to each subgrid in the 
        board, do not add duplicate random numbers.
    """
    board.clear()
    added = [0]
    for y in range(0, 9, 3):
        for x in range(0, 9, 3):
            if len(added) == 10:
                return
            i = 0
            while i in added:
                i = random.randint(1, 9)
            try:
                board.set(random.randint(x, x+1), random.randint(y, y+1), i, lock=True)
            except ValueError:
                print("Board rule violation, this shouldn't happen!")
            added.append(i)

def rgb(red, green, blue):
    """
    Make a tkinter compatible RGB color.
    """
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % (red, green, blue)

class SudokuGUI(Frame):
    board_generators = {"SudoGen v1 (Very Easy)":sudogen_1}
    board_generator = staticmethod(sudogen_1)

    def new_game(self):
        self.board.clear()
        self.board_generator(self.board)
        self.sync_board_and_canvas()

    def make_modal_window(self, title):
        window = Toplevel()
        window.title(title)
        window.attributes('-topmost', True)
        window.grab_set()
        window.focus_force()
        return window

    def load_game(self):
        def _load_game(filename):
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                board = pickle.load(f)
                if not isinstance(board, SudokuBoard):
                    # TODO: Report bad file
                    return
                self.board = board
            self.sync_board_and_canvas()
            window.destroy()
        window = self.make_modal_window("Load Game")
        fbox = FileSelectBox(window, command=_load_game)
        fbox.pack()
        window.mainloop()

    def save_game(self):
        def _save_game(filename):
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(self.board, f, protocol=2)
            window.destroy()
        window = self.make_modal_window("Save Game")
        fbox = FileSelectBox(window, command=_save_game)
        fbox.pack()
        window.mainloop()

    def query_board(self):
        window = self.make_modal_window("Set Board Algorithm")

        scroll = Scrollbar(window)
        scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        listbox = Listbox(window, yscrollcommand=scroll.set) 

        scroll.config(command=listbox.yview)

        bframe = Frame(window)

        for s in self.board_generators.keys():
            listbox.insert(-1, s)

        def do_ok():
            self.board_generator = self.board_generators[listbox.get(ACTIVE)]
            window.destroy()

        def do_cancel():
            window.destroy()


        cancel = Button(bframe, command=do_cancel, text="Cancel")
        cancel.pack(side='right', fill='x')

        ok = Button(bframe, command=do_ok, text="Ok")
        ok.pack(side='right', fill='x')

        listbox.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='1')
        bframe.pack(side='top', fill='x', expand='1')

        window.mainloop()

    def make_grid(self):
        c = Canvas(self, bg=rgb(128,128,128), width='512', height='512')
        c.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='1')

        self.rects = [[None for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
        self.handles = [[None for x in range(9)] for y in range(9)]
        rsize = 512/9
        guidesize = 512/3

        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                (xr, yr) = (x*guidesize, y*guidesize)
                self.rects[y][x] = c.create_rectangle(xr, yr, xr+guidesize, 
                                                      yr+guidesize, width=3)
                (xr, yr) = (x*rsize, y*rsize)
                r = c.create_rectangle(xr, yr, xr+rsize, yr+rsize)
                t = c.create_text(xr+rsize/2, yr+rsize/2, text="SUDO",
                                  font="System 15 bold")
                self.handles[y][x] = (r, t)

        self.canvas = c
        self.sync_board_and_canvas()

    def sync_board_and_canvas(self):
        g = self.board.grid
        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                if g[y][x] != 0:
                    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.handles[y][x][1], 
                                           text=str(g[y][x]))
                else:
                    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.handles[y][x][1], 
                                           text='')

    def canvas_click(self, event):
        print("Click! (%d,%d)" % (event.x, event.y))
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        rsize = 512/9
        (x,y) = (0, 0)
        if event.x > rsize:
            x = int(event.x/rsize)
        if event.y > rsize:
            y = int(event.y/rsize)
        print(x,y)
        if self.current:
            (tx, ty) = self.current
            #self.canvas.itemconfig(self.handles[ty][tx][0], fill=rgb(128,128,128))
        self.current = (x,y)

        # BUG: Changing the color of the background of a tile erases parts of
        #      the thick gridlines
        #self.canvas.itemconfig(self.handles[y][x][0], fill=rgb(255,255,255))

    def canvas_key(self, event):
        print("Clack! (%s)" % (event.char))
        if event.char.isdigit() and int(event.char) > 0 and self.current:
            (x,y) = self.current
            #self.canvas.itemconfig(self.handles[y][x][0], fill=rgb(128,128,128))
            try:
                self.board.set(x, y, int(event.char))
                self.sync_board_and_canvas()
            except ValueError:
                # TODO: I'd rather set the erroneous value anyway and simply
                #       not consider it valid, and perhaps set the text color
                #       to red.
                pass

    def __init__(self, master, board):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        if master:
            master.title("SudokuGUI")

        self.board = board
        self.board_generator(board)
        bframe = Frame(self)

        self.ng = Button(bframe, command=self.new_game, text="New Game")
        self.ng.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand='1')

        self.sg = Button(bframe, command=self.save_game, text="Save Game")
        self.sg.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand='1')

        self.lg = Button(bframe, command=self.load_game, text="Load Game")
        self.lg.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand='1')

        self.query = Button(bframe, command=self.query_board, text="Set Board Algorithm")
        self.query.pack(side='left', fill='x', expand='1')

        bframe.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='1')
        self.make_grid()
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.canvas_click)
        self.canvas.bind("<Key>", self.canvas_key)
        self.current = None
        self.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = SudokuBoard()
    tk = Tk()
    gui = SudokuGUI(tk, board)
    gui.mainloop()
```

I need more difficulty level to add in it such as very easy, easy, medium, hard, very hard.

Comment: `random.seed(time.time())` Why?

Answer (score 0):

To do that you would need to go through the entire code and understand what is going on. Only then will you be implement difficulty levels. That would require a good understanding of tkinter.

I personally would recommend to try and create a small app , instead of trying to figure out someone else's code.

This simple app could be a good start:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        tk.Label(self, text='Hello', bg="white", fg="black", font = ['Helvetica', 30]).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have three mutually exclusive options (easy, medium, hard), this could be a good candidate for "radio buttons."  Implementation is described well [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm).  Modifying their example, you could add something like this into your __init__ method.

```
master = Tk()

game_level = IntVar()

Radiobutton(master, text="Easy", variable=game_level, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="Medium", variable=game_level, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="Hard", variable=game_level, value=3).pack(anchor=W)
```